# Convert string with nested characters into specific json like format in java

Tags: java, json, spring, string, spring-boot

There's a string like:

```
String query = "param1, param2, param3{npam1, npam2, npam3{nipam1, nipam2}}";
```

This string needs to be processed in the format:

```
{

    param1: param1, 
    param2: param2, 
    param3: {

        npam1: param3.npam1, 
        npam2: param3.npam2, 
        npam3: {

            nipam1: param3.npam3.nipam1, 
            nipam2: param3.npam3.nipam2

        }

    }

}
```

Have already done till 2 nested, but the point is the string to query can be extended to any number of nested curls.

Comment: I formatted your question a little. Hope your expected output is in format I assumed is expected. If not feel free to rollback my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jorge. This method can be called to produce json in desired format, by passing the actual String (the one that is not formatted).

```
public String expressionConstruct(String jsonWithOutFormat) {

    jsonWithOutFormat = jsonWithOutFormat.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String json = "";
    String[] objectsInString = jsonWithOutFormat.split("[{]");
    List<String> nestedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    json += "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsInString.length; i++) {
        String[] objectAttributes = objectsInString[i].split("[,]");
        if(i==0)
            nestedObjects.add(objectAttributes[objectAttributes.length-1] + ".");
        else
            nestedObjects.add(nestedObjects.get(i-1)+objectAttributes[objectAttributes.length-1] + ".");
        for (int j = 0; j < objectAttributes.length; j++) {
            if(!(j == objectAttributes.length-1)) {
                if(i != 0)
                    json+=  objectAttributes[j].replaceAll("}", "") + ": " +  nestedObjects.get(i-1) + objectAttributes[j]  + ", ";
                else
                    json+=  objectAttributes[j] + ": " + objectAttributes[j] + ", ";
            }
            else {
                if(!(i == objectsInString.length-1))
                    json+=  objectAttributes[j] + ": {";
                else {
                    json+= objectAttributes[j].replaceAll("}", "")  + ": " + nestedObjects.get(i-1) + objectAttributes[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    json += "}";
    return json;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to iterate over the objects in the string and then iterate over the attributes of each object. Hopefully, it will help you to solve your problem. Also in your initial String, you are missing the open parenthesis and the close parenthesis so I added them.

```
    String jsonWithOutFormat = "param1, param2, param3{npam1, npam2, npam3{nipam1, nipam2}}";
    jsonWithOutFormat = jsonWithOutFormat.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String json = "";
    String[] objectsInString = jsonWithOutFormat.split("[{]");
    List<String> nestedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    json += "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsInString.length; i++) {
        String[] objectAttributes = objectsInString[i].split("[,]");
        if(i==0)
            nestedObjects.add(objectAttributes[objectAttributes.length-1] + ".");
        else
            nestedObjects.add(nestedObjects.get(i-1)+objectAttributes[objectAttributes.length-1] + ".");
        for (int j = 0; j < objectAttributes.length; j++) {
            if(!(j == objectAttributes.length-1)) {
                if(i != 0)
                    json+=  objectAttributes[j] + ": " +  nestedObjects.get(i-1) + objectAttributes[j]  + ", ";
                else
                    json+=  objectAttributes[j] + "\"" + ": " + "\"" + objectAttributes[j] + "\"" + ", ";
            }
            else {
                if(!(i == objectsInString.length-1))
                    json+=  objectAttributes[j] + ": {";
                else {
                    json+= objectAttributes[j].replaceAll("}", "")  + ": " + nestedObjects.get(i-1) + objectAttributes[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    json += "}";
    System.out.print("\n" + json);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But instead of 

npam3: {

            nipam1: param3.npam3.nipam1, 
            nipam2: param3.npam3.nipam2

        }

The Output is:
npam3: {

            nipam1: nipam1, 
            nipam2: nipam2

        }

Comment: You are right, I add some changes to the code, let me know if that work for you

Comment: Thanks! It is working. But, as said if I insert a nested object like in this case: **opam1** inside like: param1, param2, param3{npam1, npam2, npam3{nipam1{opam1}, nipam2}}, it results into:

{
 
        npam3: {

            nipam1: {opam1} :  param3.npam3.nipam1.opam1, 
            nipam2: param3.npam3.nipam2

        }
Instead, in the key value of nested objects, no curls should be there.

Comment: It's not providing the same schema as the output for more deeper nested objects. Can you please help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. It have been resolved! By making a single change inside for loop to replace '}'. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to heard that, you can edit the answer to share it with others.